# How to interrupt an HTTP handler?

Tags: http, go, handler

Say I have a http handler like this:

```
func ReallyLongFunction(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World!")
        // run code that takes a long time here
        // Executing dd command with cmd.Exec..., etc.

})
```

Is there a way I can interrupt this function if the user refreshes the page or kills the request some other way without running the subsequent code and how would I do it?

I tried doing this:

```
notify := r.Context().Done()
go func() {
    <-notify
     println("Client closed the connection")
     s.downloadCleanup()
     return
}()
```

but the code after whenever I interrupt it still runs anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to forcibly tear a goroutine down from any code *external* to that goroutine.

Hence the only way to actually interrupt processing is to periodically check whether the client is gone (or whether there's another signal to stop processing).

Basically that would amount to structuring your handler something like this

```golang
func ReallyLongFunction(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World!")

    done := r.Context().Done()

    // Check wheteher we're done

    // do some small piece of stuff

    // check whether we're done

    // do another small piece of stuff

    // …rinse, repeat
})
```

Now a way to check whether there was something written to a channel, but without blocking the operation is to use the "select with default" idiom:

```golang
select {
    case <- done:
        // We're done
    default:
}
```

This statemept executes the code in the "// We're done" block if and only if `done` was written to or was closed (which is the case with contexts), and otherwis the empty block in the `default` branch is executed.

So we can refactor that to something like

```golang
func ReallyLongFunction(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World!")

    done := r.Context().Done()
    closed := func () bool {
        select {
            case <- done:
                return true
            default:
                return false
        }
    }

    if closed() {
        return
    }

    // do some small piece of stuff

    if closed() {
        return
    }

    // do another small piece of stuff

    // …rinse, repeat
})
```

---

### Stopping an external process started in an HTTP handler

To address the OP's comment…

The `os/exec.Cmd` type has the `Process` field, which is of type `os.Process` and that type supports the `Kill` method which forcibly brings the running process down.

The only problem is that `exec.Cmd.Run` blocks until the process exits,
so the goroutine which is executing it cannot execute other code, and if `exec.Cmd.Run` is called in an HTTP handler, there's no way to cancel it.

How to best handle running a program in such an asynchronous manner heavily depends on how the process itself is organized but I'd roll like this:

1. In the handler, prepare the process and then start it using `exec.Cmd.Start` (as opposed to `Run`).

   Check the error value `Start` have returned: if it's `nil`
   the process has managed to start OK. Otherwise somehow communicate the failure to the client and quit the handler.

   Once the process is known to had started, the `exec.Cmd` value
   has some of its fields populated with process-related information;
   of particular interest is the `Process` field which is of type
   `os.Process`: that type has the `Kill` method which may be used to forcibly bring the process down.
2. Start a goroutine and pass it that `exec.Cmd` value and a channel of some suitable type (see below).

   That goroutine should call `Wait` on it and once it returns,
   it should communicate that fact back to the originating goroutine over that channel.

   Exactly what to communicate, is an open question as it depends
   on whether you want to collect what the process wrote to its standard
   output and error streams and/or may be some other data related to the process' activity.

   After sending the data, that goroutine exits.
3. The main goroutine (executing the handler) should just call `exec.Cmd.Process.Kill` when it detect the handler should terminate.

   Killing the process eventually unblocks the goroutine which is executing `Wait` on that same `exec.Cmd` value as the process exits.

   After killing the process, the handler goroutine waits on the channel to hear back from the goroutine watching the process. The handler does something with that data (may be logs it or whatever) and exits.

Comment: @Sterisk, yes, sorry for confusion.

Comment: Is there a way to interrupt a cmd.Run() inside ReallyLongFunction or can I only check closed() once it's completed?

Comment: @Sterisk, expanded by answer. But you did not tell us an important detail: does your handler somehow deliver what that process generates at runtime to the client (like piping the process' output to the client)?

Answer (score 1):

You should cancel the goroutine from inside, so for a long calculation task, you may provide checkpoints, to stop and check for the cancelation:

Here is the tested code for the server which has e.g. long calculation task and **checkpoints** for the cancelation:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc(`/`, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx := r.Context()

        log.Println("wait a couple of seconds ...")
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ { // long calculation
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                log.Println("Client closed the connection:", ctx.Err())
                return
            default:
                fmt.Print(".")
                time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond) // long calculation
            }
        }
        io.WriteString(w, `Hi`)
        log.Println("Done.")
    })
    log.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}
```

Here is the client code, which times out:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("HTTP GET")
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: 1 * time.Second,
    }
    r, err := client.Get(`http://127.0.0.1:8081/`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    bs, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("HTTP Done.")
    log.Println(string(bs))
}
```

You may use normal [browser](http://localhost:8081/) to check for not canclation, or close it, refresh it , disconect it, or ..., for the cancelation.